# Falha na leitura de um arquivo .php (lib PHPMailer)

Tags: php, html, phpmailer, debug, sublime-text

Olá! Tenho o seguinte form:

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="send_email.php" id="formContato">
            <div class="left">
                <fieldset class="mail"><input placeholder="Endereço e-mail" type="text" name="email" id="email"></fieldset>
                <fieldset class="name"><input placeholder="Primeiro nome" type="text" name="primeiro_nome" id="primeiro_nome"></fieldset>
                <fieldset class="name"><input placeholder="Segundo nome" type="text" name="ultimo_nome" id="ultimo_nome"></fieldset>
                <fieldset class="name"><input placeholder="Telefone" type="text" name="telefone" id="telefone"></fieldset>
                <fieldset class="subject">
                    <select name="assunto" id="assunto">
                  aias,      <option>Dúvida</option>
                        <option>Reclamações</option>
                        <option>Outros</option>
                    </select>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <fieldset class="question">
                    <textarea  name="mensagem" id="mensagem" placeholder="Digite sua mensagem..."></textarea></fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-holder">
                <button class="btn blue" type="submit" value="enviar" name="enviar" id="enviar">Enviar</button>
            </div>
</form>
```

e o arquivo send_email.php:

```
<?php

require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'PHPMailer';

if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){

// Fetching data that is entered by the user
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $primeiro_nome = $_POST['primeiro_nome'];
    $ultimo_nome = $_POST['ultimo_nome'];
    $mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];
    $assunto = $_POST['assunto'];
    $telefone = $_PPOST['telefone'];
    $to_id = 'emailunionjunior1@gmail.com';

// Configuring SMTP server settings
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = $to_id;
    $mail->Password = 'senha';

// Email Sending Details
    $mail->addAddress($to_id);
    $mail->Subject = $assunto;
    $mail->msgHTML($email . "\r\n" .$mensagem);

// Success or Failure
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        $error = "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        echo '<p id="para">'.$error.'</p>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<p id="para">Message sent!</p>';
    }
}
else{
        echo '<p id="para">Please enter valid data</p>';
    }
?>
```

O problema é que, quando o form é preenchido e os campos são submetidos via post para o action `send_email.php`, nada acontece nesta URL.
no caso, a URL seria: `localhost/site/index.html`, onde tem o form que é preenchido e depois, quando submetido, vai para localhost/site/send_email.php (porém, esta página fica em branco). Como estou desenvolvendo esse app no sublime text, acabo não conseguindo debugar bem a parte lógica.. (já tentei implementar o package xdebug no sublime mas tive dificuldades no uso).
já apaguei todo esse código de `send_email.php`, deixando só o `phpinfo()` para testar se de fato o `php` está funcionando (e está!).

Engraçado é que, até se eu `$email = $_POST['email'];` logo após o `<?php` e depois printar um `echo $email`, ainda assim nada aparece

Answer (score 0):

Em vista seu script está correto.

Para debug do `PHPMailer`, adicione:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
```

ou

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
```

Opções:

- `SMTP :: DEBUG_OFF (0)`: Desabilita a depuração (você também pode
  deixar isso completamente, 0 é o padrão).
- `SMTP :: DEBUG_CLIENT (1)`: Saída de mensagens enviadas pelo cliente.
- `SMTP :: DEBUG_SERVER (2)`: como 1, mais respostas recebidas do
  servidor (esta é a configuração mais útil).
- `SMTP :: DEBUG_CONNECTION (3)`: como 2, mais informações sobre a
  conexão inicial - este nível pode ajudar a diagnosticar falhas no
  STARTTLS.
- `SMTP :: DEBUG_LOWLEVEL (4)`: como 3, mais informações de nível mais
  baixo, muito detalhado, não use para depuração de SMTP, apenas
  problemas de baixo nível.

[Documentação](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/SMTP-Debugging)

> acabei de descobrir q tem algo de errado no require. – Mikhael Araujo

Você precisa acertar onde buscar o `PHPMailerAutoload.php` no seu `send_email.php`

Exemplos:

Para PHPMailer (5.2-stable) ([Link](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/5.2-stable)):

(renomeie a pasta para PHPMailer)

No mesmo diretório:

```
require_once 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
```

Diretório anterior:

```
require_once '../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
```

Caso esteja na última versão (6.0.3):

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
```

Comment: acabei de descobrir q tem algo de errado no require.

Comment: Tente assim `require_once 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';`... Provavelmente o caminho da pasta está incorreto. Se você tem a pasta do `PHPMailer` no mesmo diretório do `send_email.php` então é dessa forma. Se não, poste como está sua estrutura.

Comment: require_once 'vendor/composer/autoload_real.php';
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';

na mesma pasta do arquivo send_email.php, existe uma pasta vendor com esse diretorio..

Comment: Continuo não conseguindo instanciar um objeto de classe PHPMailer.

Comment: Você precisa chegar no `PHPMailerAutoload.php`... Então tem que ir entrando nas pastas... ex.: `require_once 'vendor/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';`.. a pasta padrão do PHPMailer, já tem o `PHPMailerAutoload.php` na raiz. Se o seu está diferente, procure pelo `autoload.php`, e faça o caminho até ele.

Comment: Adicionei na versão atual (6.0.3). https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer