# Falha ao enviar email com phpmailer

Tags: phpmailer

Eu uso o `PHPMAILER` noutro site meu onde ele está a funcionar perfeitamente. No entanto, esse mesmo código não me permite enviar emails, ele dá `Sucesso` e nenhum erro aparece. Usei o código `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;` e não encontro nenhum erro lá.

Eis o código

```
require 'mail/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();   
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;  
    $mail->Host = "servidor";  //nome do servidor está oculto
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = false;
    $mail->CharSet="utf-8";

    $mail->From = "email1";
    $mail->FromName = "Nome1";
    $mail->AddAddress("email2");
    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    $mail->Subject = "Taasd";
    $mail->Body    = $titulo;

    if(!$mail->Send()){
       echo "<script>console.log('".$mail->ErrorInfo."')</script>";
       exit;
    }else{
        echo "<script>console.log('Sucesso')</script>";
    }
```

Comment: Você está usando a porta 587 e SMTPAuth false !?

Comment: @RBZ Uhhhh sim, fiz algo de errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoje são raros os servidores que enviam sem autenticação. Se caso o seu realmente aceita, seria a porta 25.

Caso não aceite, terá que setar o usuário e senha.

Exemplo de estrutura e debug:

[Falha na leitura de um arquivo .php (lib PHPMailer)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/284795/falha-na-leitura-de-um-arquivo-php-lib-phpmailer/284800#284800)

Comment: A forma que eu pus o debug ele mostrou o processo todo e não indicava nenhum erro

Comment: Testa como o exemplo. Vamos fazer funcionar !

Comment: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER()

Comment: Dá uma olhada no link, na minha resposta. Estou no cel é difícil ficar editando resposta.

Comment: Dá exatamente o mesmo texto como o `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;  `

Comment: Obrigado pela sua ajuda, decidi usar `SMTPAuth` + as credenciais e ele envia como é suposto, não consegui usar sem autenticação

Comment: Provavelmente seu servidor de e-mail não aceita. Que bom que resolveu ! :]

Comment: Devo apagar a pergunta?

Comment: Mas a minha resposta não te ajudou ? Se sim, coloca como resolvido, se não pode apagar.

Comment: Usar autenticação como referido por si resolveu o problema